# How to type into input field with WicketTester?

Tags: java, unit-testing, wicket, wicket-tester

I'm writing a unit test for a Wicket WebPage. I want to fire up a page, type into a field, click a link, and then make some assertions.

Looking at the API of [WicketTester](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/WicketTester.html) and [BaseWicketTester](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/BaseWicketTester.html), I couldn't find any method that takes a path (like "form:input") to locate an input field and lets you enter text in it.

```
// set up WicketTester; create page
tester.startPage(page);
tester. // Type into input field - how to do this?
tester.clickLink("form:continueButton");
// assert something
```

Did I miss something? This seems like a pretty basic use case. Are you not supposed to use WicketTester like this? (That would be surprising given the presence of methods like clickLink().)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `FormTester`:

```
FormTester formTester = tester.newFormTester("form");
formTester.setValue("myformfield", "Hello Sailor");
```

**Reference:**

- [FormTester javadoc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/FormTester.html)
- [Testing Pages](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Testing+Pages) (Wicket wiki, somewhat outdated but still relevant)

Comment: Ah, so that's how you're supposed to do it. Thanks!